# Tax displays even when customer is not logged in

Tags: magento-1.8, tax

We recently upgraded a client from 1.3 -> 1.8. The taxes are now showing the default rate even if the customer is not logged in. The correct display should be no tax until a customer is logged in.

State is Minnesota, I have set the tax setting to the recommended setting from the Magento Tax configuration page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the system configuration.

*Tax > Default Tax Destination Calculation*

If a matching tax rule is configured for that address and the NOT LOGGED IN customer group, and catalog prices are configured to be displayed including tax, you will get the behaviour you describe.

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick in 1.9 as well. Added a new tax class to the not logged in customer group. Cart no longer shows tax by default for unkown addresses.